# Mounted a local directory to k8s pod, only one file is visible inside the pod, others are not

Tags: kubernetes, local-storage

So, I have some mp4 files in the local directory of my master node of k8s. I am trying to make those files available inside our application pod.
This is my deployment.yaml

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app1
        image: userhere/getting-started
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: video-storage
          mountPath: /app/video
      volumes:
      - name: video-storage
        hostPath:
          path: /home/user/vids/
```

initially I added one video (sample-vid.mp4) to the /home/user/vids/ directory, and applied this deployment file, I could see the video inside the pod.

After that, I added few more videos to the same local directory, and rollout restarted the deployment. Still, when `kubectl exec -it <podname> -- /bin/bash` inside the pod, only that previous single video is visible, all the contents inside the directory are not getting visible inside the pod.

What is missing? what am i getting wrong?

I tried deleting only the pod, then i rollout-restarted the deployment, still, only one video file is visible. Rest are not.

```
/app # ls
Dockerfile    node_modules  package.json  spec          src           video         yarn.lock

/app # cd video/
/app/video # ls
sample-vid-1.mp4
```

Comment: Please read the tag wiki for Kubernetes, or the first sentence IN ALL CAPS just below the title of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) (which is also the first sentence of the Kubernetes tag wiki).

Comment: `hostPath`-type volumes refer to a directory on whichever node the Pod happens to be running on.  This means they see different content depending on where the Pod get scheduled, and they're very rarely the storage setup you want.  IME you also rarely if ever direcly log into a node (and especially a master) and in practice you won't have permission to.  Can you upload this content to the cluster in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write something to this hostPath PV by using `kubectl cp` to copy a test file into the pod, and then execute `ls -lh` on the host machine to compare if the privileged is misconfigured.

Comment: I did kubectl cp <localpath> <podname>:<hostpath>, it copies the content for the directory inside the pod as expected. But, this will be a manual process, and thats not what I wanted. I wanted to define in manifest, and do this everytime new pod is deployed.

Comment: @that-parikshit try to run following checklist to make sure:
1) The pod is running on the correct node, that PV is having all the files that you need
2) The file inside this PV (hostPath) has the right privileged to be accessed by pod.

---- Checklist
1) `kubectl cp` a file into PV, then `kubectl exec` inside the pod, check if the file exists.
2) `ls -lh` show the file attribute
3) Back to host machine, `cd` into hostPath directory, `ls -lh` check the attribute